# Hibernate update all columns from object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following method to update a row in database using hibernate. I want to update all the columns in the table using the new object. So I get the existing object and set all of its properties to the new object's properties.

```
public void updatePlace(Place newPlace) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Place place = (Place)session.createQuery("FROM Place AS plc WHERE plc.Id = " + newPlace.getId()).list().get(0);
        place.setPhone(newPlace.getPhone());
        place.setPKey(newPlace.getPKey());
        place.setName(newPlace.getName());
        place.setDetails(newPlace.getDetails());
        session.update(place);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

In this method I update all the columns one by one, and if I add a new column one day I have to remember to change this method.

```
place.setPhone(newPlace.getPhone());
place.setPKey(newPlace.getPKey()); 
place.setName(newPlace.getName());
place.setDetails(newPlace.getDetails());
```

Is there a shorter way to update the columns using the newPlace object?

Answer (score 1):

you'd better get the object with using [get](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) method in session interface, and then update the properties of the object then use [update](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#update%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
i.e.

```
Place place = (Place)session.get(newPlace.getId());
place.setPhone(newPlace.getPhone());
....

session.update(place);
```